# "Script is broken" but works in codepen

Tags: javascript

I have a codeblock that I want to use to display projects in my portfolio that works in codepen but when I try to code it into my cargo collective site it comes back with the error that "the script is broken". The HTML and CSS are working properly only the JS is showing an error

```
<script>

const wheelEventName = (navigator.userAgent)
  ? "wheel"
  : "mousewheel";
const layers = [...document.querySelectorAll(".layer")];
const tracker = document.querySelector(".track-active");
const trackerNumber = document.querySelector(".track-number");
let itemDisplayed = 0;
let animationPlaying = false;

function resetClasses() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    layers[0].children[i].classList.remove("item-displayed");
    layers[1].children[i * 2].classList.remove("item-displayed");
  }
}

document.addEventListener(wheelEventName, event => {
  if (!animationPlaying) {
    const nextItem = itemDisplayed + Math.sign(event.deltaY);
    if (nextItem >= 0 && nextItem <= 3) {
      itemDisplayed += Math.sign(event.deltaY);
      layers[0].style = `transform: translateX(${-itemDisplayed * 85}vw);`;
      layers[1].style = `transform: translateX(${-itemDisplayed * 85 * 2}vw);`;
      layers[1].children[itemDisplayed * 2].classList.add("item-revealed");

      resetClasses();
      layers[0].children[itemDisplayed].classList.add("item-displayed");
      layers[1].children[itemDisplayed * 2].classList.add("item-displayed");

      tracker.style = `transform: translateX(${itemDisplayed * 100}%);`;
      trackerNumber.innerText = `0${itemDisplayed + 1}`;
      setTimeout(() => {
        animationPlaying = false;
      }, 2200);
      animationPlaying = true;
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Here is the codepen link that includes the HTML and CSS
https://codepen.io/pnshah115/pen/PMJBzZ

Comment: link to the broken site would help..

Comment: *when I try to code it into my cargo collective site* Whatever that means I think the site possibly rejects ES6 scripts. If I were you, I'd remove all ES6 syntax extensions (like arrow functions, string templates etc.) and try again. Both versions of the code would work in a modern browser, however you possibly hit some restrictions at the other side.

Comment: Agree with @WiktorZychla since that is most probably some sort of back end framework error since it isn't a familiar  javascript runtime error

Comment: @LawrenceCherone heres a link to the site https://shahvisuals.com/Untitled-Page everything works except the scroll effects

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was naming a function as `tryUntilDone`, so I tried different changes until found the problem. There was a **conflict with the name of the function**. So I changed the name, and now its working:

From

```
function tryUntilDone () {}
```

to

```
function _tryUntilDone () {}
```

So the error can come from many places, but this solved my problem **many times**. So dont forget to try changing your variables name.

### Another trick

Saving the same file **more than once** sometimes reports fake "script is broken" error. To avoid this error follow the steps:

1. Write some random code to make the script invalid. Save (it will report an error, obviously).
2. **Reload the page**
3. Remove the random code and save again. It will be accepted now.

Seems like executing the same script without reloading reports error and cargo thinks its an invalid script.